# strange compiler error with friend function

Tags: c++

The following code is rejected by GCC/Clang/MSVC though it seems to be able to compile.

```cpp
class B {
};
class C : private B {
    friend B& to_B(C& c) {
        return static_cast<B&>(c);
    }
};
class D : private C {
    friend C& to_C(D& d) {
        return static_cast<C&>(d);
    }
    friend B& to_B(D& d) {
        return to_B(to_C(d));
    }
};
```

Why the compilation fails?

GCC error message:

```
<source>:12:12: error: 'class B B::B' is private within this context
   12 |     friend B& to_B(D& d) {
      |            ^
<source>:3:7: note: declared private here
    3 | class C : private B {
      |       ^
```

Comment: I don't have time for an explanation about how the lookup of names work, and why this results in the given error. But you can change `friend B& to_B(D& d) {` to `friend ::B& to_B(D& d) {`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't find chapter and verse to back it up, but `C`'s private inheritance makes `B` completely private if it's looked up from within the definition of `D`.
(Essentially, `B` is first looked up in the inheritance chain, and since name lookup stops at the first match, it is private to `C`. The global definition is never considered.)

You can make it compile by modifying the name lookup procedure with an explicit scope:

```
friend ::B& to_B(D& d)
```